# Why is my MySQL query with Multiple Joins so slow?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I am trying to run a query on a table(history_details) with about 30,000 rows and need to join several tables(history, rooms, roommates, properties, listers, students, and admin).

1. The first join to the history table is straightforward.
2. The next 3 joins(rooms, roommates, properties) should only be added if the condition is met. In this case, it is looking what the value of the listing_type column in the history_details table is and should add the join to the query if it is the appropriate value.
3. The next 3 joins after that have several conditions that need to be met in order to include them, but in the case of those it could be any of the OR conditions.

   ```
                   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                       history_details.history_id,
                       history_details.listing_type,
                       history_details.listing_id,
                       history_details.date_added,
                       history_details.field,
                       history_details.before_value,
                       history_details.after_value,
                       history_details.edit_group,
                       history_details.email,
                       history_details.name,
                       history_details.correction_message,
                       history_details.photo_filepath,
                       history.history_message,
                       listers.first_name,
                       listers.last_name,
                       students.first_name,
                       students.last_name,
                       admin.first_name,
                       admin.last_name
                   FROM history_details
                   LEFT JOIN history
                       ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                   LEFT JOIN rooms
                       ON history_details.listing_type="room" AND rooms.room_id = history_details.listing_id
                   LEFT JOIN roommates
                       ON history_details.listing_type="roommate"
                       AND roommates.roommate_id = history_details.listing_id
                   LEFT JOIN properties
                       ON history_details.listing_type="property"
                       AND properties.property_id = history_details.listing_id
                   LEFT JOIN listers
                       ON (history_details.listing_type="lister" AND listers.lister_id = history_details.listing_id)
                       OR (history_details.listing_type="property" AND listers.lister_id = properties.lister_id)
                       OR (history_details.listing_type="room" AND rooms.lister_type="lister" AND listers.lister_id = rooms.lister_id)
                   LEFT JOIN students
                       ON (history_details.listing_type="student" AND students.student_id = history_details.listing_id)
                       OR (history_details.listing_type="roommate" AND students.student_id = roommates.student_id)
                       OR (history_details.listing_type="room" AND rooms.lister_type="student" AND students.student_id = rooms.lister_id)
                   LEFT JOIN admin
                       ON history_details.listing_type="admin" AND admin.admin_id = history_details.listing_id
                   LIMIT 0,100
   ```

It is giving me the correct results, but it is taking 73 seconds to run. I have added Indexes, but I am not sure if they're being used. This is what it shows when I run Explain using `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ....`

[image]

This is what it shows when I run Explain using `EXPLAIN SELECT ....`
[image]

These are the indexes I have added to the various tables:
**history_details**
[image]

**properties**
[image]

**rooms**
[image]

**roommates**
[image]

Can you tell me if my indexes are being used? Also, how can I improve my query, table structure, or indexes to improve the speed?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Amadan's helpful suggestion, it is now running at 147ms instead of 73 seconds before. This is the final query I ended up using:

```
                SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                    history_details.*,
                    listers.first_name AS lister_first_name,
                    listers.last_name AS lister_last_name,
                    NULL AS student_first_name,
                    NULL AS student_last_name,
                    NULL AS admin_first_name,
                    NULL AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN listers
                    ON listers.lister_id = history_details.listing_id
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="lister"

                UNION

                SELECT history_details.*,
                    NULL AS lister_first_name,
                    NULL AS lister_last_name,
                    students.first_name AS student_first_name,
                    students.last_name AS student_last_name,
                    NULL AS admin_first_name,
                    NULL AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN students
                    ON students.student_id = history_details.listing_id
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="student"

                UNION

                SELECT history_details.*,
                    listers.first_name AS lister_first_name,
                    listers.last_name AS lister_last_name,
                    NULL AS student_first_name,
                    NULL AS student_last_name,
                    NULL AS admin_first_name,
                    NULL AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN properties
                    ON properties.property_id = history_details.listing_id
                LEFT JOIN listers
                    ON listers.lister_id = properties.lister_id
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="property"

                UNION

                SELECT history_details.*,
                    listers.first_name AS lister_first_name,
                    listers.last_name AS lister_last_name,
                    students.first_name AS student_first_name,
                    students.last_name AS student_last_name,
                    NULL AS admin_first_name,
                    NULL AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN rooms
                    ON rooms.room_id = history_details.listing_id
                LEFT JOIN listers
                    ON (rooms.lister_type="lister" AND listers.lister_id = rooms.lister_id)
                LEFT JOIN students
                    ON (rooms.lister_type="student" AND students.student_id = rooms.lister_id)
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="room"

                UNION

                SELECT history_details.*,
                    NULL AS lister_first_name,
                    NULL AS lister_last_name,
                    students.first_name AS student_first_name,
                    students.last_name AS student_last_name,
                    NULL AS admin_first_name,
                    NULL AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN roommates
                    ON roommates.roommate_id = history_details.listing_id
                LEFT JOIN students
                    ON students.student_id = roommates.student_id
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="roommate"

                UNION

                SELECT history_details.*,
                    NULL AS lister_first_name,
                    NULL AS lister_last_name,
                    NULL AS student_first_name,
                    NULL AS student_last_name,
                    admin.first_name AS admin_first_name,
                    admin.last_name AS admin_last_name
                FROM history_details
                LEFT JOIN history
                    ON history_details.history_id = history.history_id
                LEFT JOIN admin
                    ON admin.admin_id = history_details.listing_id
                WHERE history_details.listing_type="admin"
                ORDER BY history_details_id DESC
                LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: and what does `explain select ....` shows ?

Comment: The first thing you should look in every case is the execution plan.

Comment: with OR conditions in join can also slow down query.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - I have added a screenshot of what EXPLAIN outputs without the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. It's only slightly different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm not familiar with an execution plan. Can you elaborate or provide me a link that explains that?

Comment: @Abhijeet - Yeah, I thought about that, and I am open to suggestions on how to change my query to avoid that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows where `key` is `NULL`, it is not using any indices for those tables. I.e. `listers` and `students` are unoptimised. And that is because an index on it is impossible, since you use an `OR` to produce that. Make several queries, one for each `history_details.listing_type`, and `UNION` them. Yes, it looks ugly, it's a lot of repetition, but the speed will be there.

Union syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE history_details.listing_type="lister"
UNION
SELECT ...
WHERE history_details.listing_type="property"
UNION
SELECT ...
WHERE history_details.listing_type="room"
UNION
SELECT ...
WHERE history_details.listing_type="admin"
....
...
ORDER BY whatever
LIMIT whatever, whatever
```

Be sure that each `SELECT` has the equal number of fields (so you will have to do even the useless joins, but they will be quick since they will be indexed). The `...` is basically your entire query (`SELECT field1, field2... FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON condition ...`), but with the `OR` taken out of the `lister` and `student` clauses. `UNION` will combine all the rows of the subselects. `ORDER` and `LIMIT` will apply to the result of the union, not to the last `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I am not familiar with UNION. Do you have any sample code for that? Also, if I use this approach, Will I still receive all returned rows in one result set?

Comment: Edited a rough example, the real code is a bit too long for the answer. if `SELECT A` gives you two rows, `1, 2`, and `SELECT B` gives you `4, 5, 6`, then `SELECT A UNION SELECT B` will give you 5 rows.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot. Thank you! Are you saying I need all the joins in each conditional Select statement or just the joins that pertain to that specific condition?

Comment: I was, but rethinking it it is wrong. You can leave off the joins that don't do anything (e.g. `listers` table when you're looking for `student` values), nut be sure to have equal number (and order) of fields (i.e. in the above example replace `listers.first_name` with `NULL`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's running really fast now. See my implementation in my edit above. One last issue I'm facing now is trying to add one more `WHERE` conditions after all those Unions, so this is the code im trying to add at the end of it so the user can search for a student first or last name and it will only show those (I had to use HAVING since the `WHERE` condition won't accept aliases). `HAVING (student_first_name LIKE "%'.$_GET['search_input'].'%" OR student_last_name LIKE "%'.$_GET['search_input'].'%")`. Unfortunately, this isn't giving me the results I would expect. Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT a, b, c FROM (SELECT a, b, c UNION SELECT a, b, c) WHERE a ORDER BY b LIMIT 0, 100`, with your whole previous query is in parens; but that will eliminate your listers, properties and admins since those fields are `NULL` for those queries... and also that outer 'WHERE` won't be indexed, since it'll be on a calculated temp table which has no indices. So rather than doing this, I'd stick three identical `WHERE` clauses in each `UNION`ed `SELECT` that has students.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's giving me unwanted rows that don't meet the criteria. I'm pretty sure I implemented it correctly. Instead of clogging up the comments here, do you mind if I show you in the chat real quick?

Comment: I added this before the query: `$search_sql = ' AND (students.first_name LIKE "%'.$_GET['search_input'].'%" OR students.last_name LIKE "%'.$_GET['search_input'].'%") '` and then added it after each WHERE clause, so ie: `WHERE history_details.listing_type="lister"'.$search_sql.'`
I actually need to add it to every `WHERE` clause in each SELECT since I will be adding search criteria besides student name, but when I do that, it gives me the following error: "Unknown column 'students.first_name' in 'where clause'", which I think occurs because of the SELECTS that aren't including all the joins.

Comment: Don't add the same `WHERE` everywhere. Only restrict the columns that are relevant for that particular query.